# VB.NET how does one create multiple dictionaries from a list of variables

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have to create multiple dictionaries; 80-300. Any idea how i can create these dictionaries from a list of variables? i.e.

I have ("0001","0003","0002","0005",..) I need to create a numerical list of dictionaries?

```
Dim $$$$ As Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why "multiple dictionaries"? What should be their keys/values? Did you mean a single dictionary whose key/value pairs are like `{1, "0001"}, {2, "0002"}, {3, "0003"}` etc.?

Comment: My apologies I am looking to create multiple dictionaries with the variable names like:

dic0001 = {1,"hello"}, dic0002 = {34534531,"Ja"}

Comment: So you want multiple dictionaries where each dictionary has one key/value-pair?

Comment: You can't dynamically create variable names (other than pre-compile code generation). If you could, how would you access them if the variable names are not known at compile time? Maybe you're just looking for a `Dictionary(Of Dictionary(Of Integer, String))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
Public Function CreateDictionariesDictionary(sourceList as IList(Of String)) As IDictionary(Of String, IDictionary(Of Integer, String))
    Dim returnDic As New Dictionary(Of String, IDictionary(Of Integer, String))

    For Each sourceItem In sourceList
        returnDic(sourceItem) = New Dictionary(Integer, String)
    Next

    Return returnDic
End Function
```

Then, instead accessing each dictionary by a variable name, you retrieve them from the main dictionary.

```
Dim mainDictionary = CreateDictionariesDictionary(mySourceList)
Dim dictionaryForKey = mainDictionary("key")
```